# Did Bertrand Russell mock Christians for considering humanity important?

Tags: bertrand-russell

(I am aware this question is not a philosophy question per se, but there are possibly many people here who are likely to be familiar with Bertrand Russell's writings.)

Bertrand Russell's daughter, Katharine Tait, wrote a biography of him, titled *My
Father, Bertrand Russell*.

She suggests that he mocked Christians for considering humanity important (pp.183-184):

> In his many anti-Christian writings, my father attacked over and over
> again the cowardice of religious people who could not face life
> without the comfort of their irrational beliefs. He recommended
> instead "the stark joy" to be found in "the unflinching perception of
> our true place in the world," the same proud passion I had offered my
> Harvard friend in our discussion in the library. **Christians were
> mocked for imagining that man is important in the vast scheme of the
> universe, even the high point of all creation**---and yet my father
> thought man and his preservation the most important thing in the
> world, and he lived in hopes of a better life to come. He was by
> temperament a profoundly religious man, the sort of passionate
> moralist who would have been a saint in a more believing age.

Are there examples in Russell's writings of this?

Comment: I can't steer you to readings, but it seems to me you are misreading the quote. Russell was knowledgeable about modern physics, cosmology, and biology and by those standards could not place man at the pinnacle of all creation. But he was undoubtedly a fervent humanist who regarded humankind as, for him, of supreme importance. The quote itself seems wholly at odds with your headline. You might read Russell's short work "Why I am not a Christian."

Comment: @Nelson Rather than attempting to read the quote one way or another, I am trying to learn the facts about the matter.

Comment: Yeah, I think you want to read "Why I am not a Christian".  As I recall it's a fairly easy read (for a Russell work, that is).

Comment: https://users.drew.edu/~jlenz/whynot.html

Comment: This is to me very on topic, her comment on her father's philosophy. She always loved him and defended him like a good daughter but this is to me stunning: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JEdM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JEdM.png)

Comment: @blackened I think the best answer would be that Russell though it absurd that man is important to the Universe.  That is different from saying that man is important to man.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, he did. Consider the opening of his short story *[The Theologian’s Nightmare](https://math.as.uky.edu/sites/default/files/The%20Theologian%27s%20Nightmare%20-%20Bertrand%20Russell.pdf)*:

> The eminent theologian Dr. Thaddeus dreamt that he died and pursued
> his course toward heaven. His studies had prepared him and he had no
> difficulty in finding the way. He knocked at the door of heaven, and
> was met with a closer scrutiny than he expected. "I ask admission," he
> said, "because I was a good man and devoted my life to the glory of
> God." "Man?" said the janitor, "What is that? And how could such a
> funny creature as you do anything to promote the glory of God?" Dr.
> Thaddeus was astonished. "You surely cannot be ignorant of man. You
> must be aware that man is the supreme work of the Creator." "As to
> that," said the janitor, "I am sorry to hurt your feelings, but what
> you're saying is news to me. I doubt if anybody up here has ever heard
> of this thing you call 'man.' However, since you seem distressed, you
> shall have a chance of consulting our librarian."

I won’t spoil the ending, but the story is only three pages long and worth reading in full in order to answer your question.